# Recover user phone with Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I'm using Powershell to connect to MicrosoftTeams. 
I would like to retrieve the users phone number, like I can see when access https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/users.
The cmdlet Get-TeamUser only shows UserId, User, Name and Role.

Is there any option, any other command, or any other connection that shows the phone number?

Thanks for your help.

Hernan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below commands to pull the phone number

$Msolcred = Get-credential

Connect-MsolService -Credential $MsolCred

Get-MsolUser | fl MobilePhone,DisplayName

This link will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/get-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0

Comment: Thanks @Gousia-MSFT, that's what I needed. I had tried other connections (Azure, Teams, etc) but no one brought phone number.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.